# Setting 'i' condition passed as argument

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to make a function which takes as input a data.table and condition and then modifies rows which are selected by condition. Of course I can define the condition explicitly as logical vector, like this:

```
dt1 <- fread(
       "id,a,b
       id1,1,10
       id2,2,30
       id3,3,40
     ")

test1 <- function(dtIn, condition) {
 dtIn[condition, newcol:="new text"];
 return(dtIn);
}    

test1(dt1, dt1$b>10);
```

But ideally I would like to be able to pass the condition without the table's name, something like this:

```
test2 <- function(dtIn, condition) {
 dtIn[substitute(condition), newcol:="new text"];
 return(dtIn);
}

test2(dt1, b>10);
```

I tried `substitute(condition)`, but it gives an error "`i has not evaluated to logical, integer or double`". Is it possible to implement desired functionality?

---

UPD. 
As answered by @Gregor, the correct code just uses `eval` in addition to `substitute`:

```
test3 <- function(dtIn, condition) {
  dtIn[eval(substitute(condition)), newcol:="new text"];
  return(dtIn);
}
```

It can happen also that I need to pass only the column name and build the condition inside my function. As advised from @Gregor, I can build the condition by `paste` and then use `eval(parse(...))`:

```
test4p <- function(dtIn, colName) {
  condition <- parse(text=paste0(colName, ">20"))
  dtIn[eval(condition), newcol:="new text"];
  return(dtIn);
}

test4p(dt1, "b");
```

Myself, I came to another approach which uses `get`:

```
test4g <- function(dtIn, colName) {
  dtIn[get(colName)>20, newcol:="new text"];
  return(dtIn);
}

test4g(dt1, "b");
```

The result is the same, and I am not enough competent to explain the difference here between usage of `get` and `eval(parse(...))`, so your comments are welcome. 
With `eval(parse(...))`, I was able to make function taking unquoted column name, i.e. for calling `test4(dt1, b)` (just added `substitute(colName)` to the code), but failed to do something like this without `eval(parse(...))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just missing an `eval()`.

```
test3 <- function(dtIn, condition) {
 dtIn[eval(substitute(condition)), newcol:="new text"];
 return(dtIn);
}

> test3(dt1, dt1$b>10);
           id a  b   newcol
1:        id1 1 10       NA
2:        id2 2 30 new text
3:        id3 3 40 new text
```

Even works without the `dt1$`

```
> test3(dt1, b>10);
           id a  b   newcol
1:        id1 1 10       NA
2:        id2 2 30 new text
3:        id3 3 40 new text
```

See [Hadley's Non-Standard Evaluation Section](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) for a thorough explanation.

Comment: Hadley's site is of great help indeed, I should have checked there myself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: hello again, I am just wondering if you could take a look on the question I added in "UPD." (I did not open separate question as it seems to be almost identical) - I have problems when I'm trying to pass only the column name to `i` and evaluate condition made with it...

Comment: @VasilyA Hmmm, I tried the things that I thought might work without luck. What's your use case? I'd just build up the string condition with `paste()` and then `eval(parse())` that.

Comment: Finally, I used just `get()`. But `eval(parse())` also does the job.
 (I added all this to the question.)