# passing correct environment to nested function

Tags: r, data.table

In my code, I use the function which does simple thing: takes records selected by given condition and adds give text to "errors" column:

```
dterr <- function (dtIn, condition, errtext) {
  if (!is.element('errors', names(dtIn))) {dtIn[,errors:=""];}
  dtIn[eval(substitute(condition)), errors:={paste0(errors, errtext)}];
  invisible(dtIn);
}
```

<sup>(I am thankful to people who helped with my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071896/setting-i-condition-passed-as-argument) about `eval(substitute)`)</sup>

So, in simple cases the function works as expected:

```
dt1 <- fread(
  "id,colA,colB
   id1,3,xxx
   id2,0,zzz
   id3,NA,yyy
   id4,0,aaa
     ")

myNum=0

dterr(dt1, colA>myNum, "positive");
dt1
#    id   colA colB   errors
# 1: id1    3  xxx   positive
# 2: id2    0  zzz         
# 3: id3   NA  yyy         
# 4: id4    0  aaa
```

But when I try to call it from another function, in combination with the variable defined inside, I get an error:

```
myfun <- function(){
  myNum2=1;
  dterr(dt1, colA>myNum2, "big!");
}

myfun()
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'myNum2' not found
```

Obviously, I should modify my function to pass the correct environment to `eval` - but for the moment I can't find correct solution (I played with different combinations of `parent.frame()`, `environment()`, etc). Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Wrap the body of `dterr` in `eval.parent(substitute({ ... }))` .

Comment: wow, it works! thanks! Maybe you can add it as an answer, so I will mark it accepted (I would be especially grateful if you can add just few words of explanation as I am not sure to understand exactly what happens by this code).

Comment: Surely this is not significantly different than the other question.  `substitute` substitutes the arguments into the code and then `eval.parent` evaluates the code with the substitutions in the caller's environment.

Comment: ok, I see. I was just confused that such construct leads to `{eval.parent(substitute({ ... eval(substitute(...))}))}` which blew my mind :)

Comment: You can remove the inner eval/substitute. That is `eval(substitute(condition))` becomes just `condition`.

Comment: indeed, even better so. Thanks a lot!